# Connection with DB with Python

Tags: database, python-3.x, connection, psycopg2

I have an issue with connection to DB with Python. I created a db using pgAdmin.
My code looks like below

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='Dane_Finansowe', user='dbuser', host='localhost',port=5432, password='dbpass')
```

but I got an error:

"conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

OperationalError"

I also tried to change a code, for instance:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='Dane_Finansowe', user='dbuser', host='localhost:5432', password='dbpass')
```

but then I got a different error:

OperationalError: could not translate host name "localhost:5432" to address: Unknown server error

I will be appreciated for any help. Thanks All

Comment: I tired also to reinstall pgAdmin but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never:

I had the same problem. Here is my code:

```
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5432
DB_NAME = 'postgres'
DB_USER = 'postgres'
DB_PASSWORD = 'password'

conn = psycopg2.connect(host=HOST, port=PORT, dbname=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASSWORD)
```

I got the problem because the

> DB_NAME

was not named correctly.